# Mailbox and City Registration in Germany for telecommuters

Tags: germany, residency

I work for a German company but would like to start permanently tele-commuting. In order to not create additional administrative overhead for my employer I would like to keep my tax base in Germany. I am therefore looking to move abroad but have a mailbox in Germany and, importantly, registration so that I am still considered a resident (I am an EU citizen). Is there a way to do this? Is there some company that offers tiny apartments or some other solution so that I can keep my city registration in Germany with minimal monthly costs?

Comment: This is a matter that you should ask a tax advisor that specializes in cross border tax affairs. For this, the actual country that you will be living in will probably have a double tax agreement with Germany will have to be known. Such agreements often differ from country to country and are therefore not always straightforward. As to residence laws, 'mailbox' residences (including a rented room where hundreds of peaple may be possibly registered at) will not be possible.

Comment: I know that mailbox residences are not possible in Germany. There has to be at least 13 sq. meters per registered resident in each apartment.

Comment: @Jubei, Could you provide a link to that (in German is fine)?

Comment: @ouflak I read it here: https://www.intl.kit.edu/ischolar/3331.php#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20according%20to%20the,covered%20by%20a%20health%20insurance.

Comment: I have known people (German citizens) who pulled this off by registering with family. This is clearly illegal, I would be surprised if a company could openly and durably offer it as a service. Note that the registration and “tax base” as you call it are supposed to reflect material facts: you're a German resident because you actually reside in Germany, not because you reported to some office somewhere. It would still be illegal and require you to show up from time to time but a realistic solution would be to rent an actual studio somewhere. The costs are not going to be minimal.

Comment: @ouflak [§20 Definition of residence - Bundesmeldegesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0212). The definition of the minimum size (23m²) of a residence is in: [§ 181 (9) - Grundstücksarten (Wohnung) BewG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bewg/__181.html). Note: this is per household, not per person.

Comment: @Mark Johnson: "minimum size of a residence" does not make sense to me. The law your provided is probably about minimum size of the flat and evaluation of flats / living spaces, but not about "minimum size of a residence".

Comment: @AndreySapegin The **Bundesamt für Justiz** uses the word 'residence' for 'Wohnung' in their English translations. [§ 20 Begriff der Wohnung - Bundesmeldegesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__20.html) / [§20 Definition of residence - Bundesmeldegesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0212)

Comment: They could indeed translate it like that, however, why do you use it to claim that minimum size of household in Germany is 23 m2 (your words: "this is per household, not per person")?! This is not correct, and people are definitely allowed to have smaller households. There are some limits per person mentioned in the immigration act (AufenthG), but besides it there is no limit of 23 m2 per household or "place of residence" (both notions are different from a flat). Please stop mixing laws and regulations from different areas for creating some nonexistent limitations and obligations.

Comment: @Jubel: the link you provided is relevant for inviting family members from non-EU. This is not relevant, since OP is EU citizen. Even if it would be relevant, the current version of the immigration law does not have strict limits anymore (please see AufenthG §2 Abs. 4, https://dejure.org/gesetze/AufenthG/2.html). There are indeed limits, but they depends from different laws and factors, such as land of Germany where you live, immigration status, social help, etc. E.g., in Berlin, living space should be at least 9 qm per adult (https://gesetze.berlin.de/bsbe/document/jlr-WoAufGBErahmen).

Comment: However, all the laws I cited regulate living space and they have nothing to do with "mailbox residences are not possible in Germany". Please provide a link for this statement.

Comment: @AndreySapegin **§ 181 (9) - Grundstücksarten (Wohnung) BewG** explicitly uses the word 'Haushalt' (Household). So where **23m²** is used elsewhere, Household is meant and **not** the 12m² per person quoted (that seems to come from the [Bayerischer VGH, Beschluss vom 30.10.2013 - 10 C 11.883](https://openjur.de/u/659888.html) ruling). As you state in your answers, you are not a lawyer - but you are also not a judge. Stop acting like one.

Comment: @Mark Johnson, the links you provided are simply not relevant for the discussion. The law BewG you cited is about evaluation of property (we are not talking about flat notion or costs in Germany now). §181 (9) describes how much living space ("Wohnfläche") a flat ("Wohnung") should have, but it has nothing to do with household or limits per person. The court decision is also not relevant at all, I cannot even understand which part of it you wanted to cite, or how it is related to the topic at all, did you just link a random outdated court decision here?

Comment: @AndreySapegin ouflak asked for a link for where the 13m² number came from. I provided one for the 23m² number. Nothing more. It is not a discussion and it not up to you to determine that it relevant or not.